# Max width on a <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I need to make a `<table>` which takes the full width of the parent div. But I'd like to specify a max-width on the left column, without success... Here it is my trouble:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/)

That's cleary the table { width: 100%; } but is there another way to specify a full width without Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried toying around with the overflow attribute?

Comment: I just tried with these values : auto, hidden, visible and scroll, without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `width` in the couple with `white-space: nowrap`:

```
td.leftcell
{
     max-width:    200px;
     width:        20px;
     white-space:  nowrap;
     overflow:     hidden; /* to prevent veeery long text overflow */ 
}
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/8/

Comment: I can't do this, sometimes a long text is gonna show : http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/2/

Comment: I don't want to hide the text, it has to show on a simple line

Comment: @user2428648 uh? what is "a simple line"?

Comment: I meant one line without wrapping, here I put all use cases I want to handle, the max-width would be 200px here : http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/6/ thanks for helping btw

Comment: @user2428648 you welcome. may be `white-space: nowrap;` can help , have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/7/

Comment: @user2428648 , now you have! :)

Comment: yes ^^, after severals tests, with a very long text there is a problem, maybe you can add a overflow proprety to hidden like this http://jsfiddle.net/8JLXj/12/

Comment: @user2428648 of course there will always be a chance to very long text. in my opinion it's ok to set rational `max-width` and `overflow:hidden`

Comment: I agree, as a result you can update your answer because without `overflow:hidden` it could be really ugly in some cases